# C why does a simple fgets on a txt file consume high cpu usage?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, cpu-usage, fgets

I have subtitles /srt files with data being generated by the second. I am trying to extract the data from them and save them to text files 
in a while(1) loop, its a simple text read and write operation.

But i have found out using fgets to traverse through the file is causing this simple operation to have very high cpu usage ( top command ref). more the number of fgets higher the
cpu usage.

The code bit:

```
int convert_to_txt(FILE *f1, FILE *f2) {

    static int str_len = 0;
    char cap_nxt_tmp[128];

    while (fgets(cap_nxt_tmp, 128, f1) != NULL) {

        fprintf(f2, "%s\n", cap_nxt_tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *inputFilePtr;
    FILE *outputFilePtr;

    char inputPath[1024] = "storage/sample.srt";
    char outputPath[1024] = "storage/sample.txt";
    while (1) {

        outputFilePtr = fopen(outputPath, "w");
        inputFilePtr = fopen(inputPath, "r");
        if (inputFilePtr == NULL || outputFilePtr == NULL) {
            perror("Error");
        }
        convert_to_txt(inputFilePtr, outputFilePtr);
        fclose(inputFilePtr);
        fclose(outputFilePtr);
        // theres a break on an end condition lets say least run time is an hour.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i cant understand whats wrong in the way i am using fgets to read the  srt/captions file ( 1-2 mb per file), a simple text file i/o/read operation should not consume too much cpu usage.

this basic file i/o in a while(1) of a language like python shows only a 2-3% cpu usage. 
but this in c is showing about 30% cpu usage.
How can i reduce the cpu usage without using sleep . is there any less cpu alternative to fgets?

Comment: What's wrong here is that you're doing it in a never-ending loop. Your program is going to work as hard as it can, and unless it has to block on something it's going to continue to suck up as much CPU time as possible.

Comment: the while(1) is actually terminated by "process end time" with a break . lets say this runs for an hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong or strange here.

Your main `while(1)` loop never stops, which means you're converting your files over and over again. Files get cached by the OS, so you're not really accessing your physical drives. The program therefore spends almost all the CPU time doing `strlen(cap_nxt_tmp)`, and you observe very high CPU load.

Comment: The program probably have to wait for file to change before parsing it.

Comment: yes but this is a simple text file operation. The same thing done in python pegs a very low cpu usage. How can i reduce the load in this in operation without a sleep.

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer You should rather figure out which of the 2 programs that are faster. Measure out how long it takes the C program to process 1000 files. Measure how long it takes the python program to process 1000 files. Adjust your program to the frequency you need (with a sleep). Low CPU usage might not mean your python program is faster...

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer: I don't think you can. By doing something CPU-intensive in a never-ending `while(1)` you're loading CPU at its maximum capacity, but this is *normal*. If you don't want to burn CPU cycles then just don't do it. Anyway, I don't see any point in converting the same file infinitely. In a real-life scenario you probably will be converting *different* files, doing some I/O, etc.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov so fgets is cpu intensive. yes in the actual scenario i am converting different files. The issue was when this was compared with the python program in terms of cpu usage  there was a very big difference. I was under the impression in c we could lower this cpu usage to a lot less.

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer: I can't test the Python version of your code at the moment, but I suspect that your Python program does something more than just reading the *same* file in a loop. At least this tiny Perl script `$s = "a string"; while(1) { $len = length $s; }` consumes 100% of one CPU core time, which is absolutely predictable.

Comment: +1 both the c and python program extract data and write it to txt file. is there any less cpu intensive alternative to fgets.

Comment: Not really. You might use fread(). But it solve a different problem, fgets gives you lines, fread() gives you blobs of data. If you need to read lines, use fgets(), otherwise use fread().